# unity in app purchase error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I can play my game in unity but if I try to build the game to android it does not work and error messages pop up.

error message 1 : `ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEditor is referenced by Editor ('Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/Bin/Editor.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List 1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary 2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:154)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:194)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`

error message 2 : `Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`

error message 3 : `UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:182 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`

error message 4 : `Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/Editor/IAPButtonEditor.cs(109,6): error CS0103: The name "ProductCatalogEditor" does not exist in the current context`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure you didnt delete Editor.dll from Unity/projectname/Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/Bin folder.
best of luck!